# Phonegap real resolution for Iphones

Tags: html, ios, iphone, cordova

From what I read, the Iphone 4 has a resolution of 320x480 points rendered at 2x (640x960 pixels). Similar for Iphone 5. Iphone 6Plus has 414x736 points rendered at 3x (1242x2208 pixels).

When developing my html based phonegap app, what resolution should I be using? I'm most interested in the font sizes.

Should I be using sizes that view well at 414x736 pixels? Are they rendered at 3x their size on Iphone6+? Or should I design for a size of 1242x2208 pixels directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a little bit annoying problem.

I developed like it was a responsive website.
You can add some css controls like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   p {
      font-size: 14px;
   }
}
```

So you can adjust font-size according to your screen resolution.